# Understanding the proof of $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{L}\rightarrow \Diamond$

Tags: set-theory

From what I gather the proof of $\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{L}\rightarrow \Diamond$  is pretty standard. What I don't get is how the construction of the $\Diamond$ sequence is absolute. I will reference Kunen's set theory since he is more explicit on this part of the proof. He defines the sequence $(S_\alpha,C_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ recursively and also the following:
\begin{equation}
P(\alpha,S,C)=(S,C\subseteq \alpha)\wedge (C \text{ is a club set })\wedge (\neg \exists \beta\, \in C (S_\beta=S\cap \beta))
\end{equation}
For limit ordinals $\alpha$ we define $C_\alpha,S_\alpha$ to be the $<_L$-least couple such that $P(\alpha,C,S)$ if it exists and $S_\alpha=C_\alpha =\emptyset$ in all other cases.
He says that it is absolute for transitive models of $ZF-P+\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{L}$. Being a subset is $\Delta_0$ and so it's obviously absolute. We also have that being unbounded can be expressed as $\forall x\in \alpha\; \exists y\in C\;( x\in y)$ which is also $\Delta_0$. Being closed on the other hand seems a bit more difficult. I know being a limit ordinal is $\Delta_0$ and so I guess you could write being closed as
\begin{equation}
\forall \beta \in \alpha\;(( \beta \text{ is limit } \wedge (\forall  \gamma\in \beta \; \exists \delta \in C (\delta\in \beta\wedge \gamma \in \delta)))\rightarrow \beta\in C)
\end{equation}
or $\beta$ is a limit ordinal under $\alpha$ and $C$ is unbounded in $\beta$ then $C$ contains $\beta$ is what I hope I wrote. In that case it's $\Delta_0$ and the powerset axiom was not required. Now what is not completely clear is the recursive part and the $<_L$ minimality is absolute for transitive models of $ZF-P+\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{L}$. Now I know that the order $<_L$ does not require the powerset axiom to define and so I am assuming since the construction can be carried out in the same way in $M$ that satisfies $ZF-P+\mathbb{V}=\mathbb{L}$ and so the two orders will mathc. I also know that it's $\Sigma_1$ as proved in  Jech' set theory but I don't know how that helps.